# Is there a way to add a Firebase User object to NextJs middleware and use it for route protection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, react-context

I am building a next JS application with a firebase backend. I use context for logging in, logging out and auth state changes. I would like to check if the Firebase user object exists in the middleware file and then redirect the visitor appropriately. My middleware is like below.

```
export default function middleware(req){
const { user 
} = UserAuth;
```

this however throws an error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
```

The app works and I can get the user object from other pages when i comment it on middleware
Help

Comment: Yes, you can, but you have to `initializeApp` before middleware trigger. I don't know how to do it with NEXT, but in Nuxt 3 you just do it in plugins. And you have to have in mind that first result of `onAuthStateChanges()` will be null, so your middleware might not be working when app was SSR (user opens tab with a link to a route he needs a permission)